# APOC/Neo4j: match variable length of relationships in between

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

For example, if I want to match a pattern like this:

```
MATCH (:Person)-[:A]->(:Movie)-[:B*]->(:Movie)-[:C]->(:Person)
```

where the first and last relationship's length ([:A] and [:C]) is fixed (they are both with length 1), but the middle relationship's length ([:B]) is variable.

Then the following paths will both match this pattern:

```
(:Person)-[:A]->(:Movie)-[:B]->(:Movie)-[:C]->(:Person)

(:Person)-[:A]->(:Movie)-[:B]->()-[:B]->(:Movie)-[:C]->(:Person)
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to use only one [APOC path expander](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.4/graph-querying/) procedure (say [apoc.path.expandConfig](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.4/graph-querying/expand-paths-config/)) and use the sequence to achieve this? (It seems that APOC does not support variable length of relationships in between though)

I know that I could create a new relationship between these two `(:Movie)` nodes based on this [post](https://community.neo4j.com/t/match-variable-length-paths-with-different-relationship-types/3739)
but my goal is to return the whole path all at once, including the relationship and nodes between these two `(:Movie)` nodes.

> Edited: This Cypher query can output what I want, but I want to
> compare the performance between Cypher and APOC (for research
> purposes). That's why I'm asking the equivalent way of using APOC for
> this query.

Comment: What's wrong with your current approach?

Comment: Hi, using this Cypher query can output what I want, but I want to compare the performance between Cypher and APOC (for research purposes). That's why I'm asking the equivalent way of using APOC for this query. I have edited the question to clarify this.